# Solenoid Relative Force

Tags: solenoid

For all those out there with solenoid experience I'm looking at a project using them for the [555 contest](http://555contest.com). The spec on most solenoids is ounces of force (at least in the price range I'm looking at). Aside from my disgust at the imperial units, I can fathom what the units mean, but not what kinds of things that amount of force could accomplish.

What kind of actions could 24 oz of force achieve? Is it closer to denting a peach or denting a bowling ball? Is it depended on distance? Drive current? Anything else? Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 5):

The behavior you're describing (denting stuff) is a function of **pressure** not force. I could dent a bowling ball with a few grams of force if it was in a small enough area.

I'm not just being pedantic, it's a key to thinking of what you want to do. 24oz of force (yes, it is at a specified current) can be increased over small distances using levers, or you can get a smaller force over a longer distance, again using a lever. Force is just part of the equation; you need to consider the Work that Force will do.

Answer (score 1):

Your 24oz is not telling us over what area, I'd guess with your odd imerial measurment that per foot or per inch. depending on which will make a big difference on your denting abliity.

For example if you had a nail on the end you could do some physical damage, but if its pushing a brick then it will do little at all.

24oz comes to about 6 Newtons - which is very little BTW.

Maybe posting a datasheet would be good? Little open ended.